I am trying to enter an input with the Entry tag in the AbsoluteLayout in xamarin android, but the numbers I enter are not visible
I am trying to enter an input with the Entry tag in the AbsoluteLayout in xamarin android, but the numbers I enter are not visible. It is not like this in ios. I am using the same code, it is visible in ios.
<AbsoluteLayout Padding="0,0,10,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
   <ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage   Source="resource://ClinicApp.Content.Images.SVG.ENTRY11.svg"  WidthRequest="200" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   </ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage>
   <Frame CornerRadius="30" Padding="5" BackgroundColor="Black" HasShadow="True">
     <Entry Placeholder=""  TextColor="#1a1a1a"  PlaceholderColor="#1a1a1a" TextChanged="Kod_TextChanged"  BackgroundColor="Black" FontSize="12" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20"  x:Name="Kod"  MaxLength="11"  InputTransparent="False" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1"/>
   </Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>

How can I make the entered numbers visible?
 private async void Kod_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
          
     Kod.IsVisible=true;
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Kod.Text) && Kod.Text.Length == 11)
     {
         GirisYapWSms(Kod.Text);

         Kod.IsVisible = true;
         //grd_Loading.IsVisible = true;
         //await Beklet(500);6
         //await   Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
         //
         //    //GirisYap(Kod.Text);
         //    SMSOTP smsPg = new SMSOTP();
         //    Navigation.PushAsync(smsPg);
         //});
     }          
 }


